# How to list current active systemtap probes

Tags: linux, systemtap, probe

Could anyone please tell me how to list current active systemtap probes in the system?

I guess there might be some infomation from the "/proc".

Answer (score 1):

`sysfs` has a registry of the active probes:

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/kprobes/list
```

Answer (score 1):

Brian is correct, to the extent of kprobes (kernel.*, kprobe.*).  There is no run-time catalog of all the other types of probes that may be in use (timers, perf counters, user-space probes, ...).  If such a facility would be useful, please consider opening a request for enhancement over at http://sourceware.org/bugzilla

Comment: By the way, we're adding a "--monitor" command line option to systemtap shortly, which will let the person running systemtap interact with the running probes at an ncurses-based text-ui.