Why is detaching from a uprobe using bcc so much slower than attaching?
I have a program that is attaching to 5000 functions on both entry and exit. Attaching takes some time, about 30 seconds or so. When my program exits though, the cleanup here takes upwards of 10 minutes to finish.
The C code is
typedef struct FunctionEvent_t {
  u32 pid;
  u64 timestamp;
  
  u64 func_addr;
  u8 entry;
} FunctionEvent;

BPF_PERF_OUTPUT(traceevents);

static void fill_and_submit(struct pt_regs *ctx, FunctionEvent *event) {
  event->pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
  event->timestamp = bpf_ktime_get_ns();
  event->func_addr = PT_REGS_IP(ctx);
  traceevents.perf_submit(ctx, event, sizeof(FunctionEvent));
}

int do_entry_point(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
  FunctionEvent event = {.entry = 1};
  fill_and_submit(ctx, &event);
  return 0;
}

int do_exit_point(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
  FunctionEvent event = {.entry = 0};
  fill_and_submit(ctx, &event);
  return 0;
}

The bcc code is as roughly as follows:
from bcc import BPF
bpf_instance = BPF(text=bpf_program)
path = "path/to/exe"

for func_name, func_addr in BPF.get_user_functions_and_addresses(path, ".*"):
    func_name = func_name.decode("utf-8")

    if func_addr in addresses:
        continue

    addresses.add(func_addr)
    try:
        bpf_instance.attach_uprobe(name=self.args.path, sym=func_name, fn_name="do_entry_point")
        bpf_instance.attach_uretprobe(name=self.args.path, sym=func_name, fn_name="do_exit_point")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to attach to function {func_name}")

Is there any way to speed up the detaching process? Can it the attach and detach potentially be parralellized somehow? I wouldn't have though the cleanup would be this slow.
Also to note, I have no idea if attaching to 5000 functions is sane, I'm just playing around and trying to find my systems limits.

Note, this is speculation, have not been able to test this.
There are two parts to the slowness. The first part has to do with attaching/detaching one-by-one vs in bulk. I found this issue which describes the exact same issue.
We do have multi-kprobe support nowadays via BPF links. I don't think BCC supports this, but you should be able to make use of it via libbpf.
The second part is why is detaching so much slower. This seems to be because of optimization. When you attach a kprobe it initially is unoptimized. A background optimizer will optimize attached kprobes which takes time to do and undo. So when you go and detach the kprobe it now has to undo the optimized kprobe which takes longer.
It seems an attempt has been made in the past to make this more async. However, I don't think this has been merged. But the commit message seems to confirm my optimization theory:

... I found there were another issue.
Probes: 256 kprobe_events
Enable events
real   0m 0.00s
user   0m 0.00s
sys    0m 0.00s
Disable events
real   0m 21.40s
user   0m 0.00s
sys    0m 0.02s
Remove events
real   0m 2.24s
user   0m 0.00s
sys    0m 0.01s

OK, removing events took more than 2 seconds for 256 probe events.
But disabling events took 21 seconds, 10 times longer than
removing.
Actually, since perf-events (base of BPF tracer) does disable and
remove at once, it will take more than that.
I also measured it without kprobe jump optimization
(echo 0 > /proc/sys/debug/kprobe-optimization) and it changed
the results as below.
Probes: 256 kprobe_events
Enable events
real   0m 0.00s
user   0m 0.00s
sys    0m 0.00s
Disable events
real   0m 2.07s
user   0m 0.00s
sys    0m 0.04s
Remove events
real   0m 2.13s
user   0m 0.00s
sys    0m 0.01s


So by disabling the jump optimization you might be able to make a tradeoff between detach time and runtime overhead. See kernel kprobe docs for unoptimized vs optimized overhead.

Interesting, thanks! I haven't dove into the deep details but I imagine that the kprobe bulk work can be applied to uprobes as well.
Also this is tangent and might be out of scope, but I read this comment https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/0d5dcf40bc0dd8afe5885e36241f1956cc7dabe3/src/cc/libbpf.c#L1413 and it mentions not having the clean up probes if created a specific way. What is the harm in not cleaning up these probes? Would they continuously fire or do they eventually get cleaned up by something? Not sure how that something would know what though but I'm still new to this space

Yes, bulk uprobes should also work. You should look for examples where uprobe.multi programs are being used. There is no harm in not cleaning up the probes, when your process exits, the perf events will close, triggering the detaching/unloading in the background. You will just have to convince BCC to not do cleanup. They will indeed continue to fire until the kernel gets to them to do the cleanup.

Got it, I'll definitely take a look into the bulk probes. Last question, does the optimization setting apply to uprobes? I can't find any documentation on whether it does or not

Sorry, another question. So when my bcc process exits, the events will close and that in turn removes the probes, right? Are events linked to the process that creates them, or my python script? I thought that the events were created system wide for a specific executable. I've tried finding the probes that bcc creates in the /process/debug files but I can't so I'm not sure how to actually check if they do get cleaned up

The perf events are linked to your process. When they are created as part of attaching a probe a file descriptor is returned. Like having an open file, if your process exits unexpected the OS will close the file. Same goes here, but when the process exits it removes the perf event, detaches it. And if the perf event is the only reference holder for a program it will also cause your BPF programs to be unloaded once the event(s) is gone. I do not know if there is a way to list all open perf events

Oh, just came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040802/how-to-list-current-active-systemtap-probes. Might be what you are after.

Unfortunately that's only for kprobes. I think there might be some option with bpgtrace or bpftool that can help but I'll need to dig in to it more
